# d3.js Overlay Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create an Overlay Graph. I don't understand how implement an overlay and what kind of data should be. Maybe who familiar with d3.js and have skills to build overlay graph can explain how can do that.

A similar example:
[image]

overlayGraph.js

```
var OverlayGraph = (function() {

    return {

        // Initializing the module
        /*
            dataFile - the path to the json file
            selector - place of drawing chart

        */
        init: function(dataFile, selector) {
            d3.json(dataFile, data => {
                this.drawOverlayGraph(data, selector);
            });
        },

        // Draw out data
        drawOverlayGraph: (data, selector) => {
            // === BOILERPLATE ===
            var margin = { top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100 },
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // === SVG Container === 
            var svg = d3.select(selector)
                        .append('svg')
                        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append('g')
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

            // === SCALE ===
            var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => {
                            return +d.x;
                        })])
                        .range([0, width]);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => {
                            return +d.y;
                        })])
                        .range([height, 0]);

            // === AXES ===
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom')
                    .innerTickSize(-height)
                    .outerTickSize(0)
                    .tickPadding(10);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient('left')
                    .innerTickSize(-width)
                    .outerTickSize(0)
                    .tickPadding(10);

            // === Drawing axes ===
            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'y axis')
                .call(yAxis);

            // === VIZUALIZATION ===
            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .interpolate('basis')
                .x(d => {
                    return xScale(d.x);
                })
                .y(d => {
                    return yScale(d.y);
                });

            svg.append('path')
                .attr('d', line(data))
                .attr('class', 'line');
        }

    }

})();

OverlayGraph.init('data.json', 'body');
```

My data looks like:

```
[
    { 
      "x": "0", 
      "y": "5" 
    },
    ...
]
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is an area https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#areas 
you have to find a way to define the bottom value and the top value on the area for each point of you line and then do a

```
var area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(d.data.date); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.bottomValue); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.topValue); });

   g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", area);
```

see https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211

Comment: thank you for your advice. I have added some fields in my json-file and used your solution. As a result, it turned out that it is necessary. Thanks again.